# Correct understanding of a .NET stack trace with delegates

Tags: c#, .net

I'm trying to get a deeper understanding of each frame in a .NET stack trace. Most stack traces are easy to understand. I also know about packages like Ben.Demystifier to make it even more readable. Here's an example of a stack frame I'm trying to understand better:

```
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Controllers.ControllerBinderDelegateProvider.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<<CreateBinderDelegate>g__Bind|0>d.MoveNext()
```

As I understand this, the `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Controllers` part is the namespace, `ControllerBinderDelegateProvider` is a class, and `MoveNext()` is a method. What about the `<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<<CreateBinderDelegate>g__Bind|0>d` part can someone help explain what this cover?

Comment: There are generated .NET nested classes that correspond to higher level C# constructs. You can dig around that using a tool such as ILSpy: https://github.com/icsharpcode/ILSpy

Comment: Looking in ILSpy, dotPeek, or something similar is a good idea 

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16401860/what-does-displayclass-name-mean-when-calling-lambda

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<<CreateBinderDelegate>g__Bind|0>d` part is generated by the C# compiler. In the cited case, it is specifically generated for [the local function `Bind`](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/8bb128185b58a26065d0f29e695a2410cf0a3c68/src/Mvc/Mvc.Core/src/Controllers/ControllerBinderDelegateProvider.cs#L74) in the method `CreateBinderDelegate` that belongs to the class `ControllerBinderDelegateProvider`, and which sits under the namespace `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Controllers`.

To understand the various part of the name, follow [`GeneratedNames.MakeLocalFunctionName`](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/blob/d1e617ded188343ba43d24590802dd51e68e8e32/src/Compilers/CSharp/Portable/Symbols/Synthesized/GeneratedNames.cs#L110) in the compiler/Roslyn source code. It calls the main workhorse method [`MakeMethodScopedSynthesizedName`](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/blob/d1e617ded188343ba43d24590802dd51e68e8e32/src/Compilers/CSharp/Portable/Symbols/Synthesized/GeneratedNames.cs#L120).

The implementation details may change over time, but for now, here's a rough breakdown of `<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<<CreateBinderDelegate>g__Bind|0>d`, which you can see as being composed of several parts:

1. `<>c__DisplayClass0_0`
2. `<CreateBinderDelegate>g__Bind|0`
3. `<...>d` or `<<CreateBinderDelegate>g__Bind|0>d`

Note that in the third case, the second one is embedded.

All the synthesized names created by `MakeMethodScopedSynthesizedName` have the following pattern based on parameter names:

```
"<" methodName? ">" kind
  ( "__" suffix suffixTerminator? )?
  ( methodOrdinal ("#" methodGeneration )?
  | entityOrdinal ("#" entityGeneration )?
  | methodOrdinal ("#" methodGeneration )?
    "_"
    entityOrdinal ("#" entityGeneration )?
  )?
```

In the above pattern, anything in quotes (`"..."`) is a literal, parentheses (`(...)`) are used for grouping, `?` means optional, `|` means *or*, and identifiers like `methodName` and `suffix` represent the value of `MakeMethodScopedSynthesizedName` arguments.

The `<>c__DisplayClass0_0` part is generated by a call to [`GeneratedNames.MakeLambdaDisplayClassName`](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/blob/d1e617ded188343ba43d24590802dd51e68e8e32/src/Compilers/CSharp/Portable/Symbols/Synthesized/GeneratedNames.cs#L46):

```cs
MakeMethodScopedSynthesizedName(GeneratedNameKind.LambdaDisplayClass,
                                methodOrdinal, generation,
                                suffix: "DisplayClass",
                                entityOrdinal: closureOrdinal,
                                entityGeneration: closureGeneration);
```

Since `methodName` is null, the synthesized name starts with `<>`, the `c` comes from [`GeneratedNameKind.LambdaDisplayClass`](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/blob/d1e617ded188343ba43d24590802dd51e68e8e32/src/Compilers/CSharp/Portable/Symbols/Synthesized/GeneratedNameKind.cs#L18), the suffix is clearly `DisplayClass` and the `0_0` comes from assuming that `methodOrdinal` and `generation` are zero for that call.

You can follow the sources to see how the other parts are built with a variation of arguments to `MakeMethodScopedSynthesizedName`, but in brief:

- The `<CreateBinderDelegate>g__Bind|0` part is generated by a call to [`GeneratedNames.MakeLocalFunctionName`](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/blob/d1e617ded188343ba43d24590802dd51e68e8e32/src/Compilers/CSharp/Portable/Symbols/Synthesized/GeneratedNames.cs#L110).

  ```cs
  MakeMethodScopedSynthesizedName(GeneratedNameKind.LocalFunction, methodOrdinal, methodGeneration, methodName, localFunctionName, GeneratedNameConstants.LocalFunctionNameTerminator, lambdaOrdinal, lambdaGeneration);
  ```
- The `<...>d` part is generated by [`GeneratedNames.MakeStateMachineTypeName`](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/blob/d1e617ded188343ba43d24590802dd51e68e8e32/src/Compilers/CSharp/Portable/Symbols/Synthesized/GeneratedNames.cs#L76) where the `...` comes from the `methodName` value:

  ```cs
  MakeMethodScopedSynthesizedName(GeneratedNameKind.StateMachineType, methodOrdinal, generation, methodName);
  ```