# How to invoke lambda method that is non-static using MethodInfo (uses <>c__DisplayClass1)

Tags: c#, lambda

Consider the following code:

```
bool result;

Func<int, bool> lambda1 = i => i == 9000;
MethodInfo lambda1Method = lambda1.Method;
result = (bool)lambda1Method.Invoke(null, new object[] { 9000 }); // this works, result = true

int myLocalVariable = 9000;
Func<int, bool> lambda2 = i => i == myLocalVariable;
MethodInfo lambda2Method = lambda2.Method;
result = (bool)lambda2Method.Invoke(null, new object[] { 9000 }); // error
```

Invoking `lambda2Method` results in a `System.Reflection.TargetException`:

> Non-static method requires a target.

This question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6013094/why-does-code-generate-msil-class-called-c-displayclass1) explains why the `lambda1Method` is static, while `lambda2Method` is non-static. Basically if lambdas contain local variables, a class is dynamically created that interprets each local variable as a field. `lambda2Method` becomes an instance method of that new class. I know this because `lambda2Method.DeclaringType` is `<>c__DisplayClass1`, and `lambda2Method.IsStatic` is `false`.

My question is, how can I make this work? I understand that because `lambda2Method` is non-static, I need to supply a value for the `object obj` parameter of `MethodBase.Invoke()`, and it needs to be an instance of `<>c__DisplayClass1`, but how do I obtain this instance?

Comment: pass `this` instead of null

Comment: @M.kazemAkhgary this does not work.

Comment: What is wrong with `result = lambda2.Invoke(9000);` ? Why converting to `MethodInfo` ?

Comment: @user3185569 Absolutely nothing, but the project I am working on involves using the `MethodInfo Delegate.Method` property.

Comment: @MrAnderson Ok, then check the edited answer on how to create an instance using reflection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main issue that you need to address in you question is *How to create an instance of a type generated by the compiler ?*

So, if you really have to use `MethodInfo`, then you can create the required instance by using Reflection:

```
var instance = Activator.CreateInstance(lambda2Method.DeclaringType);

result = lambda2Method.Invoke(instance, new object[] { 9000 });
```

**Summary:**

The declaring type for your method `lambda2` is a hidden class generated by the compiler. `MethodInfo.Invoke` requires a target instance of that type to invoke a non-static method.

**Edit:**

To get the captured value of `myVariable` correct, you can make use of the `Target` property :

```
result = lambda2Method.Invoke(lambda2.Target, new object[] { 9000 });
```

Comment: It does let me create the instance using `Activator`, but the value of the field `myLocalVariable` is 0, not 9000, so `result` is false.

Comment: @MrAnderson That's because we created a new instance of that type.

Comment: @MrAnderson You can use `lambda2.Target`, check the edited answer.